# Cantor-like functions for $\xi\neq \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, cantor-set

Let $\xi \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$. Let $C_\xi$ be the perfect symmetric set built by iterating the transformation
$$[0,1] \to [0,\xi]\cup [1-\xi, 1].$$

The set $C_\frac{1}{3}$ would then correspond to the Cantor set. Define the $\xi$-Cantor-like function as the limit of the piecewise linear functions $f_i$ which are constant on the intervals removed in the $i$-th iteration for constructing $C_\xi$, see Wikipedia [1] for a pictorial analysis.

Can we show that the procedure for constructing the $\xi$-Cantor-like function will still yield a well-defined limit function, the $\xi$-Cantor-like function, which will be surjective and (since its monotone) continuous?

[1] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function, last accessed 28/02/2022 at 11:35 PM GMT.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to construct an uncountable number of mutually singular atomless measures on $[0,1]$. If I can define Cantor-like functions using these sets $C_\xi$, I will be pretty much finished as these functions will be my distribution functions

Comment: The problem with showing surjectivity is that most arguments for the surjectivity use the close relationship of the Cantor function to the ternary base, which these Cantor-like functions lack, I believe

Comment: This relationship can be salvaged for $\xi\ne 1/3$. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** For the original Cantor function with $\xi=1/3$, surjectivity can be proven by relying on the uniqueness of the base-$3$ representation of real numbers in $[0,1]$, and the fact that the Cantor function can be described as a transformation from base-$3$ digit sequences to base-$2$ digit sequences. This type of argument can actually be generalized to arbitrary bases $\xi\in (0,1/2)$, although it's not immediately clear how.

Define $3$ functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ as follows:

$$f_1(x) = \xi x \\ f_2(x) = \xi + (1-2\xi)x \\ f_3(x)=(1-\xi) +\xi x$$

It happens that every real number $x\in[0,1]$ can be expressed as the limit of a sequence $(d_n)$ taking the form

$$d_1 = f_{n_1}(0) \\ d_2 = f_{n_1}\circ f_{n_2}(0) \\ d_3 = f_{n_1}\circ f_{n_2}\circ f_{n_3}(0) \\ \cdots$$

where each $n_i$ equals $1,2,$ or $3$. When $\xi=1/3$, the functions $f_i$ are given by

$$f_1(x) = \frac{1}{3} x \\ f_2(x) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}x \\ f_3(x)=\frac{2}{3} +\frac{1}{3} x$$

so that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ can be seen as shifting the base-$3$ representation of $x$ one digit to the right and appending a $0,1,$ or $2$ respectively, and the approximations $d_1,d_2,d_3,\cdots$ are $n$-digit base-$3$ numbers whose $n$ digits agree with the most significant $n$ digits of $x$. Hence the analogy with the $\xi=1/3$ case - we are generalizing the base-$3$ representation to values $\xi\ne 1/3$. The values of $n_1,n_2,\cdots$ are analogous to the "digits" of $x$ under this alternative base representation system.

My suggestion is the following: show that any $x\in [0,1]$ has a unique representation in the described form for any $\xi\in (0,1/2)$, determine how the Cantor function transforms these sequences into base-$2$ sequences, and deduce that the Cantor function is surjective from the fact that every base-$2$ sequence has a preimage.

Comment: Thanks for your very  comprehensive  answer, although I don’t fully understand it yet. When you say that the number $x$ can be expressed as the limit of a sequence $d_m=\bigcirc_i^m f_{n_i}(0)$ given a sequence $(n_i)_{n\ge 1}$, did you mean $d_m=\bigcirc_i^m f_{n_i}(x)$? Also how is $(n_i)_{n\ge 1}$ determined?

Comment: No, I meant $f_{n_i}(0)$, not $f_{n_i}(x)$. As for how exactly the $n_i$ are determined, I leave that detail up to you. However, I would urge you to look at how these formulas reduce in the case of $\xi=1/3$ - in particular, they are equivalent to the base 3 representation, which should give some insight.

Comment: I’m now trying to prove these sets are disjoint. It basically reduces to the problem in this question below, I hope you have an idea to share: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394691/summation-of-powers-do-not-coincide?  noredirect=1#comment9190290_4394691